# Inserting 2D elements into a static 2D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to know if it's possible to add 2D elements, so a 1D array, to a 2D array without iterating over each element in the 1D array. Like adding an entire row instead of individual elements.

Something like this, where a[5][0] and a[5][1] are initialized to 0.

```
int a[6][2] = { {0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6},{4,8}};
int i, j;
a[5] = {1,2};
```

Comment: What did the compiler tell you about `a[5] = {1,2};`?

Answer (score 0):

No. That's not possible in C.

You can't "insert" an array at an index in another array.

If you need to do something like that, depending on your application/need, you can either go for dynamic memory allocation `malloc()`/`realloc()` then resize the memory and copy the elements as necessary. Or use a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and insert a "node" (where each node represents/contains the small array) into the list and then iterate over the list.